# PWM FAN controller & Ideal 24V DC to DC 5V Converter just to feed 556 IC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I'm trying to find a best match for a regulator that can feed dual timer ic. The 5V circuit is dedicated to that IC which will generate a PWM pulse signal to  PWM control the FAN speed. It's a 4 pin PWM fan, the 5V will not feed the fan!

**Input Voltage:** 24V

**Input max tolerated voltage:** 26V

**5V line consuption:** +/- 30mA, 50-100mA margin needed

**Requirements:** Small, good availability, easy to source, less components, low noise, cheap (Don't want isolated AIO solutions which costs a few bucks each), SMD, no zenners!

**Circuit:**
[image: Circuit]

On my research found the following solutions:

1. Linears regulators: From 24V to 12V L7812 to 5V L7805, i'm not a big fan of them but for the purpose they may fit?
2. Bucks: MP1584 (overkill, big), AOZ1282CI (Smaller but still overkill). Then i come across with LT1107 and LT1111 which are simple and low current.

But i'm sure there's a better solution out there that i'm not aware. What you guys would use in that situation?

**25/05/2019, Updated circuit**

[image: Circuit 2]

[image: PCB]

**27/05/2019, Updated circuit, Final**

- Added extra fan header to take advantage of empty space
- Change pot circuit to use Jack solution
- Reduced PCB overall size
- Removed Foot switch and use pot with switch
- Change P mosfet to N mosfet

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Linear Regulators seens do the job just fine in this situation, as indicated and helped out by @DaveTweed on comments.
Thank you

**Edit - 25/05/2019:**

End in use LM2936HVMAX-5.0/NOPB to support higher voltages to use with higher voltage fans, up to 58V (If needed)

**23/06/2019, Fixed and Updated circuit v1.1**

- Added alternative XH headers for fan and power, eg. regular fan header
- Added solder jumper for test or ignore headers
- Added solder jumper to select 2/3/4 fan wire operation
- Added more information about pins on board
- Fixed wrong mosfet footprint
- Changed VH orientation, now tab faces out the board
- Better label positions and reorder
- Compact board and components
- Better thermals

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Anyway, for less than 40-50 mA, I'd go with linear; above that, switcher. Specific product recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, the fan pwm signal must be 5V, i think, not sure if it will fry with higher voltage but fan datasheet says **PWM signal voltage: 5V**, don't wana risk with 12V and invalidate the fan.
About consumption i can't tell now but i will be happy with 100mA margin, because all i need is that generated signal from the timer.

Comment: On my prototype i used the LM7805 for speed build and it work fines but heat a little over time, that's why i indicated dual linears to outcome future heat problems

Comment: Measured current on my prototype right now, it draw 26mA when feeding pwm to fan, and 7.7mA if i unplug fan

Comment: In that case, the LM7805 is fine. It's dissipating about 0.5W, so put a small heatsink on it and make sure it gets some airflow.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you

Comment: The fans want an open-collector PWM signal, so use pin 12 instead of pin 9

Comment: if you have several fans put a schottky diode in series with the signal to each.

Comment: There is no real benefit to having linear regulators linked together. Sure, your 5V will run cooler, but all the heat will just end up on the 12V instead. So just use a 5V on its own, with a heat sink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposed schema to control a 4-wire fan is NOT in spec.

You need to read and understand the specification for the 4-wire fan you are using.

Probably the best historical document describing the fan spec was produced by Intel on Formfactors.org, that site is long gone but you can get the document [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110726062453/http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/4_Wire_PWM_Spec.pdf).

In this document the PWM freq is stated as 21-28kHz and the PWM drive signal MUST be an open collector/Drain drive (in other words a pullup resistor or active pullup was NOT permitted). The voltage on the PWM pin was no more than 5.25V, but this was set by the fan ....not the driving elements. In some fans avaialble today, if you actively pullup the PWM pin or connect to two fans you get the wrong speed. Most of the early fans had a limited low speed range too, with 20-30% full speed not unusual.

Things have changed over the years and many fan manufacturers have improved their specifications. One example [here](http://www.delta-fan.com/PWM.pdf) for the Delta fans which can use a PWM freq of 30Hz- 30kHz, tolerates active pullup and 10V PWM amplitude.
Arctic fans are [another example](https://www.arctic.ac/us_en/p-fan-faq/), with their own specification for multiple fans (up to 4) on one PWM signal line.

> Your proposed PWM fan control

I would suggest that the operation using a 556 timer may have problems.

1. You are using active pullup, which may not work depending on the fan.
2. You mention using 16kHz which may not work depending on the fan.
3. Your freq and pulse width controls will interact.
4. T1 does absolutely nothing. I think perhaps you meant to create a CC source with T2, but what you have does not work that way. At high temperatures you may find T2 is turning on sufficient to reset your 556. If you are depending on simply the R3C5 time constant your timing is way out, T2 may be on for 8-10 Tau.

As a suggestion you may be better to design a solution based on an ATTiny85 driving an AO3400 or AO3402 for the PWM output. It would be a lot less components and board space. 
The ATTiny would require about the same current (12-15mA) as you might use for the 556 timer so **a small SOT-89 78L05 would be adequate to power the MCU**.

**Update:**
Since the OP has now posted details of the fan being driven, it's possible to show some of the hazards to not following the 4-wire fan spec.

The fan is a Sanyo-Denki [9BMC24P2G001](https://www.sanyodenki.com/archive/document/product/cooling/catalog_E_pdf/San_Ace_E.pdf). The datasheet has little detail of the PWM signal, but the Catalog shows on page 551 the following information on the PWM signal:

[image]

Clearly from this information you can see that providing an active pullup may actually damage the PWM signal input or in your case would simply shut down the +5V regulator. The only way to drive this type of input is open collector/drain. To use active pullup you would require either a series resistor to limit current or a series Schottcky diode.

**Update_1:**

The new circuit is a vast improvement over the old one, with just a few comments:

1. If you want to drive multiple fans then simply add more AO3400 FETs

[image]

1. It appears you want to switch between an internal Pot and an external Pot. I would suggest the following change to ensure safer wiring and predictable failure modes.

[image]

With the circuit above you don't feed +5V into your wiring, so it's safe from short circuits.
Using two A/D inputs allows you to easily separate both the function and scale of the external versus internal Pot.
Providing a limited scale for the pots means you can detect an open circuit wire, or a faulty pot.

I have no idea what your intent is for this piece of the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i will take a look at formfactors document. I built that circuit based on this: https://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/641111-Building-PWM-Controller-for-4-wires-PWM-fan?p=6473318&viewfull=1#post6473318 
The post says: "Both circuits are using PWM frequency that is set according to FormFactors standard for 4 wires PWM fan -> http://www.formfactors.org/developer...e_PWM_Spec.pdf"
I have that circuit implemented on a test board and so far it worked with every fan i have toss in, PC fans, agressive delta and san ace fans like 9BMB24K201, 9BMC24P2G001...

Comment: The fan i'm using now for the project is 9BMC24P2G001, 25Khz PWM which is what circuit is generating, so ignore **2.** as that is just a note about 16hz, not used on circuit. About **3.** i also saw that, not sure why they put it like that but the function works, i didn't try to remove T1 and test out but i can do that and see the results. Using a MCU will require software burn and extra work, i prefer keep it only with hardware

Comment: @TiagoConceição I'm sorry , but the link to overclockers seems like a good example of what NOT to do with your fans. While mentioning the Intel spec, they then break all the rules. Still if it works for you, go for it. I'd suggest you not connect PWM signals together (multiple fans driven by one signal). If you want to drive multiple fans use Schottcky diodes as already suggested in the comments.

Comment: It works, but if not the correct way i rather fix it now and use the correct spec. So for the fix i must remove that R1, and exchange traces from 9 and 12?

Comment: @TiagoConceição I would honestly suggest you abandon the 555/556 based controller and buy a 4-wire controller ...there are dozens to choose from ...see here: https://www.thetechlounge.com/best-fan-controller/ and here is a China/Ebay special: https://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-PWM-PC-CPU-Fan-Temperature-Control-Speed-Controller-Module-High-Temp-Alarm/112174066548  Notice that they al provide for ONE fan per controller port, the only multifan capability I know of is the Arctic fan, which supports 4 PWM signals in parallel ...but of course has feedback from only one fan.

Comment: Can't use modules, i require a custom PCB since it will integrate in a enclosure i'm bulding with custom headers/IOs,  i must have 1 fan header, dc in header, switch header, 2 pot headers and pot switch header as well a foot switch for power with plug detection. And also don't like to solder custom board into PCB. 
So in end i will have to build the circuit for PWM. If 555/556 can't solve i can go with your suggested attiny solution. What do you recommend?

Comment: @TiagoConceição I added an update to the answer. You have insufficient specification to give much more help, but I think I have shown what you proposed is likely not to work or be reliable.  If you want to tackle this problem with a small MCU, then you have to do some study I assume. Read up on driving a 4pwire fan from Arduino to start with, and then how to read a potentiometer using the A/D inputs. If all this is beyond you them hire professional help.

Comment: Thank you Jack, main question was about dc convertion but this end to be more usefull than expected. I probe the 556 on oscilloscope and PWM signal become very lousy when fan is connected and turning, don't know how that circuit worked so many time before with 2 fans connected in parallel. So i will go other route. Programing is ok for me, i have redraw the circuit and updated on main OP. I think the concept is correct now, one question i have: will not use two fans, but if required in future when put more fans, the use of diode still required, it's correct to use that or can have problems?

Comment: 1. The simple solutions always the harder to think off :D I notice you used only one pair of resistors, that's ok to use in this case or was to speed up the drawing? A resistor pair per FET is more recommended?
3. The T1 FET is to control fan VCC, ON or OFF, and to protect FAN from accidental reverse polarity, maybe not needed but is a extra protection. When footswitch is LOW, PWM will be set to 0 and FET VCC disabled, if PWM signal is damaged user can still turn on or off, as well 3 pin fans. But i will change R5 to pulldown instead and let MCU decide to start or not the fan at startup.

Comment: 2. Yes user can switch from the internal control on enclosure and a remote control where they can place anywhere, they both have same function, control fan speed, but can only use one or another, and remote pot is optional to have. I have to test out your circuit to full understand it, one thing that's strange to me is the wiper shorted to GND, so the sense pin will be your **pot_int** and **pot_ext** right? Also skiping the switch...

Comment: 1. Two resistors are all that is required. 2. Separating Pots allows you to check for faults, you can still use a switch. 3. You can't drive the FET gate from an MCU 5V signal created after your Reverse protection FET

Comment: I've tested your pot circuit and it makes sense now, still i have to keep switch as no other way to know what user wan't use, i also replaced foot sw by a pot with switch, more pratical and less parts, with your circuit only need 3 wire instead of 5 to operate that two functions (Speed & On/Off).

Comment: About FET i'm not sure if i understand what you mean, the FET i'm using operate with TTL signal and i don't want to operate it under a reverse condition. It act as protection to fan, without it VCC and GND if reversed will blow fan circuit. Also with that i can operate a 2/3 pin fan and keep the speed function, on schematic FET looks like NPN but it's a PNP, since i don't had a PNP variant package on Eagle to insert. The linear regulator will provide protection to MCU, so in any fault case it must save the fan.

Comment: Added a new revesion on OP, this may inspire other people so i'm sharing

Comment: After build and try circuit in the PCB something is wrong... AO3400 always die, resistance from G to E or/to S keep droping down to low ohms, i measured (when power off) 300ohm at lowest value, before first power up is in the Kohm scale. After replace 3x same happen, something is killing the mosfet... Meassured R2 and both sides give clean PWM and correspondent voltage. But at T2 E it keep at 4.5V no matter what PWM is being feed to G, but when PWM is 0, E=24V, maybe that 24V from PWM Fan pin is killing the T2?

Comment: The AO3400 is a FET ...not a transistor. The Source is ground so sgould always be at zero volts. The Drain should be rising to whatever the Fan puts out on it's PWM pin.

Comment: Ok i found what is killing the FET! My osciloscope (SDS-2204X).
https://i.imgur.com/RKBdWm3.jpg
How i use it: I put probe at R2/T2 Gate and GND aligator to GND, as soon i turn it on FET goes bad! Here my meassures after FET die: Drain to Source: 73Ohm. Gate to Drain: 70 Ohm. Gate to Source: 26Ohm. Both T2 and T3 instant damage near short to ground. What i'm doing bad at probing?

Comment: Still theres something wrong, because if i i don't use my osciloscpe with new FET in, circuit works and FET stay healthy all the time, but FAN is always at full power or OFF. PWM signal at T2 Gate is correct, goes from 0 to 4.5V but at T2 Drain stays at 4.5V or 24V when PWM is 0. If i remove FET and probe with osciloscope, the correct PWM wave can be observed at R2, but when fan start to speed up, noise can be observed, i have made a video (T2 & T3 removed from board): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2MTS-edXr0.
NOTE: Fan goes OFF when PWM is = 0 because T1 cut FAN GND

Comment: Code are: https://pastebin.com/jwnfvybZ

Comment: Basic test. Unplug the fan PWM signal. with the PWM signal floating the fan should be at full speed. With the signal shorted to ground it should stop. Next, connect a 1k Ohm resistor from T2 Drain to 24V. You should get a PWM signal that goes from zero - 24V.  Report back.

Comment: With the signal shorted to ground it should stop: Check.
PWM signal that goes from zero - 24V: No, fixed 24V at Drain. Tested with Gate from 0 to max pot value, observed 0V to 4.5V at Gate.
To discard bad FET batch i removed a BS870 from a old laptop MB and put there, same result.

Comment: OMG i just found the problem, so stupid... On PCB Gate is exchanged with Source, so PWM from MCU is going to Source, and GND to GATE at T2 and T3. Schemantic looks correct but maybe a messed up package that i use with wrong footprint. Hand solder wires to fix the problem and works OK.
There's any FET with my pin configuration so i can buy instead trash a lot of PCBs?

Comment: @TiagoConceição Glad it's working. You could solder in a TO92 package I guess ….but best to find the correct footprint.

Comment: Yes i'm fixing right now on layout, will update soon the revision on OP to not put others in same trouble. Two more questions: 
1. About noise i observed on 24V rail, if add a 220uf cap on FAN will benefit the circuit?
2. A protection diode is needed for back induction protection? If no, the same apply if drive a 2 wire fan with the T1 for speed regulation?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the noise on the 24V supply. No benefit from adding a cap, though it would do no harm either. NO, you don't need a diode across the fan no matter whether the fan is 2, 3 or 4 wire. The fans are BLDC motors and driven by their internal drivers. No spikes.   ...that is quite a thread we created. Glad it worked out for you. Good luck with the project, you now have a nice fan controller.

Comment: Great! Agreed... It start with a different question in mind and end in a much more usefull information, not only for me but i guess for others, all information i found online is based on 2 wire fans switching fet and the 4 pin fan they use 555 or arduino PWM directly to fan PWM with resistor in serie. The most correct solution i found out there is using a "EMC2305" fan driver, otherwise only see incorrect uses.

Comment: I may release sources to a github project after test the new version. Also thinking in do expansion board with tons of headers for fans.
My project is a fume extractor for solder fumes.
Thank you for all your help, I'll be happy to send you assembled board if you want (free) or a donation.

Comment: About FET dying, i think the solder temperature is killing too, 350ºc put FET near short, 300ºc OK but if to much time at legs same will happen. Do you know if AO3400 are that sensitive?

Comment: You certainly can burn them, but I have not had any problems and used lots of them.

Comment: Ordered 100 from aliexpress, maybe they are not the original thing, costs about 1.2 bucks, in fact BS870 resists more but also die, or maybe they recover after a period of time when cold, have to test this better. I have updated OP with new version :D Hope everything goes well this time. The v1 was my first boards i ever turn into a  real PCB using fabs.

Comment: After tune software everything works flawless, The only thing that brother's me now is the potetiometer acts like log instead of linear (He is linear btw). I guess is code related maybe my range is not correct. Video aplying +/- same rotation steps: https://youtu.be/j0e3ovDqcts Code: https://pastebin.com/raw/jwnfvybZ -- #define ANALOG_POT_MIN_VALUE 0
#define ANALOG_POT_MAX_VALUE 926  // 4.557V